# Integration of a tag based file system approach in Gnome and Nautilus

Tags: gnome, nautilus, filesystem, files

I am using Gnome 3.8 and Nautilus and I am quite satisfied in principle. Yet I dislike the traditional hierarchical file system approach using paths. It may be me but I often cannot find the files I am looking for in a short period of time. Thus I would like to transition to a tag based file system.

Now I am curious. Are there any tag based approaches, programs that do integrate neatly into Nautilus and Gnome?

With which one did you have good experiences?

Answer (score 6):

I've found tmsu to be the best, it can be found here:

http://tmsu.org/

It doesn't integrate into Nautilus as such but as it uses a FUSE filesystem, it can be browsed from any file manager or even on the commandline.

Comment: Sorry to revive a super-old thread, but it appears there is an integration for Nautilus 3: https://github.com/talklittle/tmsu-nautilus-rs

Comment: And also the [TSMU](https://github.com/oniony/TMSU) project appears to be dead on GitHub atm. There are no binaries beyond Ubuntu 16, so the only way to install on newer systems is compiling from source (i.e. getting Go compiler, using the Makefile, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is a nice file system level solution to your need called [NHFS](http://rffr.de/nhfs) or nonhierarchical file system. Also available a FUSE based mountable file system called [TMSU](http://tmsu.org/) that may satisfy you. Since these tow are solving your problem in a file system level, they are fully compatible to Gnome and Nautilus.

Comment: NHFS seems to be interesting, but be careful since there seems to be no further development. On the other hand: if you test it, than you can give feedback for further development

Answer (score 3):

Also if you are looking for a program such as a collection manager, and not a file system; best open source working solution in Ubuntu I can introduce is [tagspaces](http://www.tagspaces.org/). It seats independently besides nautilus, no integration at the moment.

Comment: TagSpaces is not completely free. Its 'PRO' version costs 39 € per year. Its free version is limited. "In the PRO version of the application you can add tags and description to every folder managed in TagSpaces. " https://www.tagspaces.org/documentation/metafileformats/#foldermeta

Comment: Also, it renames your files. 
(Although the PRO-version has a Beta-feature for using sidecar files instead)

Comment: The sidecar file solution is now available in the free (Lite) version as well (yay!).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Tagsistant](http://tagsistant.net/)
It's also a file system solution. However, it doesn't (at time of writing) have plugins for integrating with Gnome/Nautilus, although something like this may be possible, contributors willing.

Comment: Tagsistant has no information about integration with Nautilus: 
https://www.tagsistant.net/search?searchword=nautilus 
Moreover, some problems are reported with that (if you delete a tag directory, you go into an endless loop and everything freezes): https://www.tagsistant.net/kunena/0-6-feedback/74-not-stable-enough?start=6#133. I would downvote, but have not enough reputation.